# Providing internal WinForms app to development team

Tags: .net, deployment

So I developed an application (utility), to help with some of our text editing in house here. I developed it with WinForms using .NET 4.0 in VS2010.

What's the easiest way to make it available for team use, just to send out the .exe file in the /bin directory in an e-mail? (Or zipped up b/c Outlook would complain about an .exe), or is there a better/easier/more professional way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any option that gets them the executable, as well as any other required assemblies, will work.

That being said, you'll also need to make sure that they have the appropriate .NET framework installed.  A setup project would allow you to make a true installer for the program that would handle dependencies correctly, and can be created in Visual Studio very easily.

Comment: How would I go about creating a setup to send around instead?

Comment: @slandau: In Visual Studio, you can create a new project that's a "Setup Project" - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx

Comment: while I agree, often there's an additional requirement of deploying updates (which team members may put off installing).

Answer (score 2):

You can make [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) installer.